# error property subscribe doesn't exist on type void when subscribe data from service?

Tags: javascript, typescript, angular7, angular-components

I work on angular 7 app I face error property subscribe doesn't exist on type

void when subscribe data from service .

error display on subscribe data function on app.component.ts
so How to solve this issue if possible ?

```
allReportCategories:any[];
ngOnInit() {


       this._displayreport.getallReportCategories().subscribe((data: any[]) => {  
        this.allReportCategories = data;  

      }); 
}
```

on display report service ts

```
allReportCategories:any[];


getallReportCategories(){

    return 

     this.allReportCategories=[
    {
        "reportCategoryID": 1,
        "reportCategory": "Dashboard Parametric",
        "isDeleted": false,
        "menuIcon": "icon-home"
    },
    {
        "reportCategoryID": 2,
        "reportCategory": "Monitor Reports",
        "isDeleted": false,
        "menuIcon": "icon-list"
    },
    {
        "reportCategoryID": 3,
        "reportCategory": "Other Reports",
        "isDeleted": false,
        "menuIcon": "icon-docs"
    },
    {
        "reportCategoryID": 4,
        "reportCategory": "PCN Flow",
        "isDeleted": false,
        "menuIcon": "icon-list"
    },
    {
        "reportCategoryID": 5,
        "reportCategory": "Compliance By Document",
        "isDeleted": false,
        "menuIcon": "icon-home"
    }
];

  }
```

sample exist on stackbliz as below :

```
https://stackblitz.com/edit/create-1arrvm?file=app%2Fdisplayreport.service.ts
```

to more specific on my question

what i change here :

```
this._displayreport.getallReportCategories().subscribe
```

Comment: I might be missing something here, but the function "getallReportCategories" on your service  is only returning an array and not something that can be observed/subscribed to?

Comment: so what i change or do to solve issue

Comment: actually i need to represent data from allReportCategories on app.component.ts so what id o to solve issue

Comment: can you write correct way to send array of data above to component.ts

Comment: this meaning no need to make subscribe or what

Comment: If you need the data one time, then just return the array. If the action is async, then just await the returnvalue by Promise or callback. I assume you know what Observables and ".subscribe()" does and that you are not using code you don't understand yourself. There are cases where you expect a return value multiple times without some repeating function-call and that's where you might want to consider using subjects/events/observables :) In your case, again, just return the array and reveice it on the other end. No need to subscribe here.

Answer (score 1):

you need to create observable to subscribe

example:-

in display report service ts

```
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs';


getallReportCategories(){

const allReportCategories = [
    {
        "reportCategoryID": 1,
        "reportCategory": "Dashboard Parametric",
        "isDeleted": false,
        "menuIcon": "icon-home"
    },
    {
        "reportCategoryID": 2,
        "reportCategory": "Monitor Reports",
        "isDeleted": false,
        "menuIcon": "icon-list"
    },
    {
        "reportCategoryID": 3,
        "reportCategory": "Other Reports",
        "isDeleted": false,
        "menuIcon": "icon-docs"
    },
    {
        "reportCategoryID": 4,
        "reportCategory": "PCN Flow",
        "isDeleted": false,
        "menuIcon": "icon-list"
    },
    {
        "reportCategoryID": 5,
        "reportCategory": "Compliance By Document",
        "isDeleted": false,
        "menuIcon": "icon-home"
    }
];


    return new BehaviorSubject(allReportCategories)

  }
```

in component

```
allReportCategories:any[];
ngOnInit() {


       this._displayreport.getallReportCategories().subscribe((data: any[]) => {  
        this.allReportCategories = data;  

      }); 
}
```

Comment: can i send data without subscribe meaning suppose i dont need subscribe this can be done or mandatory must subscribe

Comment: Please read into what observables and subscriptions are. There are a tons of easy to understand tutorials out there. There is no sense in trying to explain you basic stuff here when there are better tutorials on the internet/youtube :) And please NEVER use code you don't what it is doing. If you encounter a word like "subscribe()" and don't know what it does, then learn about it. Using code you don't understand is very risky and will lead nowhere mid-/longterm^^°